# How to call WordPress function from other files

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi All i am in word Press

I am successfully integrate WordPress membership plugin and all data of users is save in database. different users have different Levels

My major task is to disable some website button according to users levels . so i try to Get user id in report.php using

```
require_once("/wp-load.php");
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

**But it gives internal 500 error** my directry structure is /myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/report.php

Comment: first of all, you can't just  call `wp_get_current_user()` and get user just from code. you need to wrap it into some function  and hook into some action, where the user will be defined. also, where located your code?

Comment: Do you use `wp_get_current_user()` function inside a plugin file?

Comment: my code is located in report.php 

 /myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/report.php

Ok so i have to hook in  
/myproject/wp-content/themes/function.php file  
and then call that function  In report.php

Comment: @Sandra no i am not call that in plugin file 
 please see my last comment it will elaborate more

Comment: `require_once("/wp-load.php")`, this line is throwing fatal error. you're trying to call non-existing file.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan well  
so can you tell me how to access current user id

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan but "wp-load.php" is in myproject directory (which is actually the root folder )

Comment: @Sandra i am really thank full to you yes wp-load.php is called and it not give inter server error please place this un answer i will surely accept it 
thanks again ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );

require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

This will give correct path of `wp_load` file.